# Uncaught ReferenceError: say is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, bundle, browserify, liquid

I try to import my `function hello()`from hello.js to my page sign_up.liquid.
I browserify my main.js to have a bundle.js(`browserify ./public/js/main.js -o ./public/js/bundle.js`) but i have an Uncaught ReferenceError. Why I can't use my `function hello()`in sign_up.liquid ?

[image]

--hello.js

```
var hello = function(){
    console.log('I said Hello')
}

module.exports = hello;
```

--main.js

```
const say = require('./hello.js')
```

--bundle.js

```
(function(){function r(e,n,t){function o(i,f){if(!n[i]){if(!e[i]){var c="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!f&&c)return c(i,!0);if(u)return u(i,!0);var a=new Error("Cannot find module '"+i+"'");throw a.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",a}var p=n[i]={exports:{}};e[i][0].call(p.exports,function(r){var n=e[i][1][r];return o(n||r)},p,p.exports,r,e,n,t)}return n[i].exports}for(var u="function"==typeof require&&require,i=0;i<t.length;i++)o(t[i]);return o}return r})()({1:[function(require,module,exports){
var hello = function(){
    console.log('I said Hello')
}

module.exports = hello;
},{}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
const say = require('./hello.js')

},{"./hello.js":1}]},{},[2]);
```

--sign_up.liquid

```
[...]
<script src="../js/bundle.js"></script>
<script>
    say.hello();
<script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is because Hello is your export, and so on your import hello() becomes say.

If you used just

```
say()
```

you should get the value of the hello() function.

Alternatively, you can use the destructuring method to give your export an alias.

Something like this:

```
const { hello: say } = require('./hello.js');
```

More information on [Destructuring here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
Specifically, you may want to check out the section named: **Assigning to new variable names** about half way down the page.